# DialogPreference causes FC

Tags: android, xml, preferences

I'm trying to implement a DialogPreference in the preferences layout. Unfortunatly, the code below always causes a force close. EditTextPreferences work well but I need a simple dialog.
Any suggestions what's wrong here?

```
<DialogPreference
        android:id="@+id/reset_languages"
        android:negativeButtonText="@string/no"
        android:positiveButtonText="@string/yes"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/reset_languages"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/reset_languages_confirmation"
        android:title="@string/reset_languages"
        android:summary="@string/reset_languages_summ" />
```

Comment: And what java are you using with this?

Comment: this is the error: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11451): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #127: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor ... Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: android.preference.DialogPreference

Comment: I think you should drop the "title" and "summary" attributes as they are not supported in XML (code only). [dev android DialogPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by extending the DialogPreferences class